# C++ should all member variable use accessors and mutator

Tags: c++, oop

I have about 15~20 member variables which needs to be accessed, I was wondering 
if it would be good just to let them be public instead of giving every one of them 
get/set functions.

The code would be something like

```
class A { // a singleton class
public:
    static A* get();

    B x, y, z;
    // ... a lot of other object that should only have one copy
    // and doesn't change often

private:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    static A* a;
};
```

I have also thought about putting the variables into an array, but I don't
know the best way to do a lookup table, would it be better to put them in an array?

EDIT:

Is there a better way than Singleton class to put them in a collection

Comment: Can you describe what kind of member variables you have? Your question is not a yes or no question because it all depends on the context.

Comment: The Singleton pattern is not regarded as a good one. There is plenty of information about this online and also here on SO. Think about why you want to have this design? Is it purely because you find it convenient to access all these things from anywhere?

Comment: Another intersting thing to know is how these members variables depend on each other and what they conceptually are. Will the user of `A` use multiple members at the same time? If you give some info about how they relate to each other and how the usage is it would be easier to know what you're after here.

Comment: These objects are a global properties, is there a better way than Singleton class to put them in a collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ world isn't quite as hung up on "everything must be hidden behind accessors/mutators/whatever-they-decide-to-call-them-todays" as some OO-supporting languages.

With that said, it's a bit hard to say what the best approach is, given your limited description.

If your class is simply a 'bag of data' for some other process, than using a struct instead of a class (the only difference is that all members default to public) can be appropriate.

If the class actually does something, however, you might find it more appropriate to group your get/set routines together by function/aspect or interface.

As I mentioned, it's a bit hard to tell without more information.

EDIT: Singleton classes are not smelly code in and of themselves, but you do need to be a bit careful with them. If a singleton is taking care of preference data or something similar, it only makes sense to make individual accessors for each data element.

If, on the other hand, you're storing generic input data in a singleton, it might be time to rethink the design.

Comment: 'The C++ world isn't quite as hung up on [getters/setters] as some OO-supporting languages.' - nor, in fairness, as many in the C++ world itself *used* to be.  Experience shows it's overrated - useful sometimes but not the necessity it was once widely characterised as.  And in fairness, languages like C# now provide most of the benefits of get/set without actually needing them, as a post-facto move to functions doesn't affect the client interface: that's definitely better, just not practical for C++ without constant performance penalty or compile time code modification / JIT etc..

Comment: it's mainly system data, the Class B have getters/setters, would it make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

You could place them in a POD structure and provide access to an object of that type :

```
struct VariablesHolder
{
  int a;
  float b;
  char c[20];
};


class A
{
  public: 
    A() : vh()
    {
    }

    VariablesHolder& Access()
    {
      return vh;
    }
    const VariablesHolder& Get() const
    {
      return vh;
    }

  private:
    VariablesHolder vh;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain why that is preferable to making them public?

Comment: @Mike I haven't said it is preferable way of doing things, but this way all variables are grouped and there are only two methods to provide access to them (which can be removed and made public access to the vh member variable), instead of having 40 get/set methods.

Answer (score 2):

No that wouldn't be good. Image you want to change the way they are accessed in the future. For example remove one member variable and let the get/set functions compute its value.

Comment: "The code will also be faster." - almost certainly not faster if the get/set functions are defined in the class definition, so the flexibility vs speed issue only arises if (a) the speed difference is measurable to begin with, and (b) you need flexibility at link-time rather than just flexibility at compile-time. I suppose they're faster to access in the sense that the programmer doesn't have to type `()` if they're public data members.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on why you want to give access to them, how likely they are to change, how much code uses them, how problematic having to rewrite or recompile that code is, how fast access needs to be, whether you need/want `virtual` access, what's more convenient and intuitive in the using code etc..  Wanting to give access to so many things may be a sign of poor design, or it may be 100% appropriate.  Using get/set functions has much more potential benefit for volatile (unstable / possibly subject to frequent tweaks) low-level code that could be used by a large number of client apps.

Given your edit, an array makes sense if your client is likely to want to access the values in a loop, or a numeric index is inherently meaningful.  For example, if they're chronologically ordered data samples, an index sounds good.  Summarily, arrays make it easier to provide algorithms to work with any or all of the indices - you have to consider whether that's useful to your clients; if not, try to avoid it as it may make it easier to mistakenly access the wrong values, particularly if say two people branch some code, add an extra value at the end, then try to merge their changes.  Sometimes it makes sense to provide arrays *and* named access, or an enum with meaningful names for indices.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible design choice, as it allows any component to modify any of these variables. Furthermore, since access to these variables is done directly, you have no way to impose any invariant on the values, and if suddenly you decide to multithread your program, you won't have a single set of functions that need to be mutex-protected, but rather you will have to go off and find every single use of every single data member and individually lock those usages. In general, one should:

1. Not use singletons or global variables; they introduce subtle, implicit dependencies between components that allow seemingly independent components to interfere with each other.
2. Make variables const wherever possible and provide setters only where absolutely required.
3. Never make variables public (unless you are creating  a POD struct, and even then, it is best to create POD structs only as an internal implementation detail and not expose them in the API).

Also, you mentioned that you need to use an array. You can use `vector<B>` or `vector<B*>` to create a dynamically-sized array of objects of type B or type B*. Rather than using `A::getA()` to access your singleton instance; it would be better to have functions that need type `A` to take a parameter of type `const A&`. This will make the dependency explicit, and it will also limit which functions can modify the members  of that class (pass `A*` or `A&` to functions that need to mutate it).

Answer (score 0):

As a convention, if you want a data structure to hold several public fields (plain old data), I would suggest using a struct (and use in tandem with other classes -- builder, flyweight, memento, and other design patterns).

Classes generally mean that you're defining an encapsulated data type, so the OOP rule is to hide data members.

In terms of efficiency, modern compilers optimize away calls to accessors/mutators, so the impact on performance would be non-existent.

In terms of extensibility, methods are definitely a win because derived classes would be able to override these (if virtual). Another benefit is that logic to check/observe/notify data can be added if data is accessed via member functions.

Public members in a base class is generally a difficult to keep track of.